# Scipy least_square with jacobian

Tags: python, scipy, camera-calibration

I am trying to replicate a camera calibration optimization using scipy.

The algorithm work fine without jacobian (the optimization converges towards optimal results).
Yet, when adding the jacobian function, the least-square function barely iterates and stops without converging.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
# Camera projection function
def project(params,points_2D, points_3D):
    """
    This function takes in 3D points and camera parameters,
    and returns the projected 2D points.
    """
    fx, fy, cx, cy = params
    X, Y, Z = points_3D
    x = fx * X / Z + cx
    y = -fy * Y / Z + cy
    return np.array([x, y])
# Jacobian function
def jacobian(params,points_2D, points_3D):
    fx, fy, cx, cy = params
    X, Y, Z = points_3D
    nb_pts = points_3D.shape[1]
    J = np.zeros((2*nb_pts,4))
    for i in range(nb_pts):
        J[2*i:2*i+2, :] = np.array([
            [X[i]/Z[i], 0, 1, 0],
            [0, Y[i]/Z[i], 0, 1]
        ])
    return J
# Residual function for least_squares
def residuals(params, points_2D, points_3D):
    """This function computes the residuals, i.e., the difference between the observed 2D points and the projected 2D points."""
    projected_points = project(params,points_2D,points_3D)
    return ((projected_points - points_2D.T)**2).flatten()


# Initial guess for the camera parameters
params0 = np.array([1050, 1000, 320, 240]) # Optimal parameters are [1000, 1000, 320, 240]


# Example 3D points
points_3D = np.array([
    [0, 0, 3],
    [20/100, 0, 2],
    [0, -1/100, 1]
])

# Example 2D points
points_2D = np.array([
    [320, 240],
    [420, 240],
    [320, 250]
])
pts = residuals(params0,points_2D,points_3D.T)
print(pts)
# Perform optimization
result = least_squares(residuals, params0, jac=jacobian, args=(points_2D, points_3D.T), verbose=1)
# Print the optimized camera parameters
print(result.x)
pts2 = residuals(result.x,points_2D,points_3D.T)
print(pts2)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your jacobian is wrong. For instance, the derivative of `g2 = -fy * Y / Z + cy` with respect to fy is `- Y / Z`, not `Y / Z`.

That being said, it's worth mentioning that `least_squares` only expects the function that evaluates your *residuals*, not the evaluated euclidean vector norm of your residuals. This means that you don't need to square inside your residuals. Otherwise, you're sort of trying to solve a least-squares of least-squares problem. Also, `project` should return a flattened numpy array with shape `(2*N)` instead of `(N,2)`, as the former corresponds to a vector and that's what's expected in a `least_squares` setting from a from mathematical point of view. Consequently, you no longer need to flatten the result inside your `residual` objective function. Last but not least, there's also no need for loops to build the jacobian, you can exploit numpys vectorized array arithmetic. More than welcome side-effect: The jacobian is way easier to read, IMO.

TLDR: This could snippet should yield the expected results:

```py
def project(params, points_2D, points_3D):
    """
    This function takes in 3D points and camera parameters,
    and returns the projected 2D points.
    """
    fx, fy, cx, cy = params
    X, Y, Z = points_3D
    g1 = fx * X / Z + cx
    g2 = -fy * Y / Z + cy
    return np.array([g1, g2]).flatten()


def jacobian(params, points_2D, points_3D):
    fx, fy, cx, cy = params
    X, Y, Z = points_3D
    N = points_3D.shape[1]
    J = np.zeros((2*N, 4))
    J[:N, 0] = X / Z     # derivatives of g1 w.r.t to fx (derivatives of g2 w.r.t to fx are all zero)
    J[N:, 1] = - Y / Z   # derivatives of g2 w.r.t to fy (derivatives of g1 w.r.t to fy are all zero)
    J[:N, 2] = 1         # derivatives of g1 w.r.t to cx (derivatives of g1 w.r.t to cx are all zero)
    J[N:, 3] = 1         # derivatives of g2 w.r.t to cy (derivatives of g1 w.r.t to cy are all zero)
    
    return J


def residuals(params, points_2D, points_3D):
    """This function computes the residuals, i.e., the difference between the observed 2D points and the projected 2D points."""
    projected_points = project(params, points_2D, points_3D)
    return (projected_points - points_2D.T.flatten())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain in what the jacobian is wrong? Also, why define a (2N,4) jacobian an only fill out the first Nx4 elements?

Comment: I just tested the solution. Whilst the new projection and residual functions improve the convergence (without jacobian), the given jacobian does not work.

    J = np.zeros((2*N, 4))
    J[:N, 0] = X / Z
    J[:N, 1] =  - Y / Z
    J[:N, 2] = 1
    J[:N, 3] = 1


Such jacobian is a little bit better but still not as accurate as no jacobian at all.

Comment: Sorry, there were indeed still some tiny typos in my jacobian. I edited my answer accordingly. For instance, your jacobian is definitely wrong as there's a missing minus sign in front of `Y[i]/Z[i]`. Other than that, your residuals and the `project` function should return a vector, not a matrix. Consequently, your jacobian becomes a matrix, not a 3d tensor.

Comment: Thank you, it now makes much more sense. The additional comments were useful.
If we want to add distortion parameters, I guess we can follow the same process, but we would have to derive with respect to g1' and g2', the distorted g1 and g2 functions. If we want to optimize the extrinsic, would you recommend doing it with the same optimization function or separately?